# Unique value for person last name and first name class in hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

Hi I want to have a unique last name and first name for my person table in my database .
my hibernate xml map for person is

```
package com.me.POJO;

public class Person {

private int personId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String streetAddress;
private String aptNo;
private String city;
private int zipCode;

public Person(){}
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress,
String aptNo, String city, int zipCode) {
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
this.aptNo = aptNo;
this.city = city;
this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public int getPersonId() {
return personId;
}

public void setPersonId(int personId) {
this.personId = personId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getStreetAddress() {
return streetAddress;
}

public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
}

public String getAptNo() {
return aptNo;
}

public void setAptNo(String aptNo) {
this.aptNo = aptNo;
}

public String getCity() {
return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
this.city = city;
}

public int getZipCode() {
return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

}
```

my Hibernate hbm.xml file for person is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Apr 9, 2012 2:49:54 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.me.POJO.Person" table="Person">
<id name="personId" type="int">
<column name="personId_PK" />
<generator class="native"></generator>
</id>
<property name="aptNo" type="java.lang.String">
<column name="aptNo" />
</property>
<property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
<column name="city" />
</property>
<property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
<column name="firstName" />
</property>
<property name="lastName" type="java.lang.String">
<column name="lastName" />
</property>
<property name="streetAddress" type="java.lang.String">
<column name="streetAddress" />
</property>
<property name="zipCode" type="int">
<column name="zipCode" not-null="true" />
</property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

is there any way i can add unique constraint in the person mapping in the hbm file so that my first name and last name are unique in the database/

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a natural key that containing `last name` and `first name` using the [`<natural-id>`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-naturalid) element.

Please note that `<natural-id>` only help to create an unique constraint on the natural key columns when the table schema is generated by Hibernate `hbm2ddl` . Hibernate will not  do any uniqueness validation on  `<natural-id>` columns at the run-times.

So , if you don't plan to re-create the table schema using Hibernate  , you can simply manually  adding the unique constraint for these columns using DDL and let the database check the uniqueness.

Comment: Marking first and last name as NaturalId will require them to be unique in the table, but then Hibernate will *prevent* them from being committed ever for that entity.  To update either field, you will have to create a new object from the old object, modify the first or last name.  Finally, you will have to replace all the occurances of the first object in collections, objects, arrays, etc... with the new object.

Comment: Additionally, NaturalIds *can* also be marked as "mutable".  I don't know if there are any disadvantages to doing that.

Comment: thanks a lot guys , now its working. I made a compound key in the database and followed.